# How do I clear screen in julia-app mac OS-X?

Tags: julia

**How do I clear screen in julia-app mac OS-X **

In mac terminal - `clear` would clear the terminal screen.

How do I do the same in julia interactive app in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 7):

## Use [keyboard shortcut](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/interacting-with-julia/#key-bindings): `Ctrl + L`.

## Use Julia's REPL [shell mode](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/interacting-with-julia/#shell-mode):

```rb
julia> ; # upon typing ;, the prompt changes (in place) to: shell>

shell> clear    # unix

shell> cmd /c cls    # windows
```

## If you need a function you could use the [`run`](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/running-external-programs/?highlight=run) function:

```
julia> ? # upon typing ?, the prompt changes (in place) to: help>

help?> run
INFO: Loading help data...
Base.run(command)

   Run a command object, constructed with backticks. Throws an error
   if anything goes wrong, including the process exiting with a non-
   zero status.

julia> using Compat: @static, is_unix    # `Pkg.add("Compat")` if not installed.

julia> clear() = run(@static is_unix() ? `clear` : `cmd /c cls`)
clear (generic function with 1 method)

julia> clear()
```

This works in a platform and version independent way (tested in Windows and Linux, Julia versions 0.3.12, 0.4.5 and 0.5.+).

Answer (score 1):

Try `Ctrl+L` if you want to clear the screen the interactive shell runs in. Same as `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer

Create a function `clear()` to print new line characters

```
clear() = for i in 1:20
       print("\n")
   end
```

Then invoke the function

```
clear()
```